# Unexpected Result When Using Sinc Interpolation

Tags: sampling, interpolation, resampling

[image]

blue is how I tried to sinc interpolate. why would something like this happen?

Comment: Maybe do it in Frequency Domain - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25131.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Sinc based Interpolation requires you to know the data at any point. Hence it is not feasible.

You might do a Truncated Sinc Interpolation.
The artifacts you're seeing can be caused by a kernel which is too short or the parameters aren't good.

In order to create a good Sinc kernel you need to know things about the Band Width of the signal and the Sampling Rate.
Did you took those into account?

Comment: I just zoomed to a part of the signal. the signal goes to zero and it is sampled often enough

Comment: Could you post the MAT file of the data and the M file you are running?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sLYWrH5q

Comment: I tried extending the sinc I convolved my samples with 100 times, it gave acceptable results.

Comment: Dra, i don't think the problem is from not choosing good parameters.  grd just ain't doing it right.  looks like the OP might be using $|\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)|$ instead.

Comment: I couldn't access his code, is it there?

Comment: @Drazick http://pastebin.com/aEwDv012 this should be available

Comment: @Drazick i posted it as an answer

Comment: How boundaries are handled is also important aspect.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=linspace(-.5,.5,256);
x=exp(-pi*t.^2*16).*(sin(2*pi*40*t)+0.154*cos(2*pi*47*t)-1.454*cos(2*pi*27*t));
figure;plot(t,x)

tt=linspace(-.5,.5,256*8-7);
xorj=exp(-pi*tt.^2*16).*(sin(2*pi*40*tt)+0.154*cos(2*pi*47*tt)-1.454*cos(2*pi*27*tt));
figure;plot(tt,xorj)

xf=SincInt(x,8,1);
sh=0;
xf=[ xf(1+sh:end) zeros(1,sh)];
figure;plot(tt,xf)
hold on;plot(tt,xorj)
figure;plot(tf,xf-xorj)

function f = SincInt( f,k ,varargin)
% function f = SincInt( f,k ,varargin)
% varargin=1 to keep the beginning and the end the same

nargin=length(varargin);

N=length(f);
f=[zeros(1,N*(k-1)) f];
for  i = 1: N
    f(k*i-k+1:k*i)= [zeros(1,k-1) f(N*(k-1)+i)];
end

f=conv(f,sinc(-60:1/k:60),'same');

if(nargin==1 && varargin{1})
    f=[f(k:length(f)) ];
end

end
```